# Soma em uma Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Estou aprendendo como usar tabelas com **PIVOT** no Sql-Server. Tenho uma tabela com o nome do item, o nome do vendedor e id do cliente.

`Item    | Customer |   ID Rep
Pen Set  | 1001     |  Richard
Binder   | 25092    |  Nick
Pen Set  | 5149     |  Morgan
Binder   | 5453     |  Susan
Pen Set  | 55456    |  Matthew
Pencil   | 5470     |  Richard
Desk     | 481      |  James`

Criei a PIVOT para mostrar os a quantidade de itens que cada vendedor vendeu, e meu código ficou assim

```
select * from(
select 
        [Item]
        ,[Customer ID]
        ,Rep
from
        [dbo].[WRK_Transacoes] 
) as TabUm 
Pivot (
    count([Customer ID])
    FOR [Item]
    IN ([Binder]
        ,[Desk]
        ,[Pen Set]
        ,[Pen]
        ,[Pencil])
)as PivotTable
```

Com a seguinte saída: 

`Vendedor|Binder|Desk|Pen|Set Pen|Pencil
Alex       2      0   1    0       2
Bill       2      0   0    1       2
James      1      1   0    1       1
Matthew    1      1   2    0       0
Morgan     1      0   1    0       1
Nick       1      0   0    1       0
Rachel     1      0   0    0       3
Richard    3      0   2    1       2
Smith      1      1   0    0       1
Susan      1      0   1    1       0`

Agora, gostária que tivesse uma coluna mostrando o total dos itens que cada vendendor vendeu. Como faço isso?
Abaixo o exempo de como quero minha tabela

`Vendedor|Binder|Desk|Pen|Set Pen|Pencil| Total
Alex       2      0   1    0       2       5
Bill       2      0   0    1       2       5
James      1      1   0    1       1       4
Matthew    1      1   2    0       0       4
Morgan     1      0   1    0       1       3
Nick       1      0   0    1       0       2
Rachel     1      0   0    0       3       4
Richard    3      0   2    1       2       8
Smith      1      1   0    0       1       3
Susan      1      0   1    1       0       3`

Desculpe o tamanho da pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução passa por calcular o total de artigos que cada vendedor vendeu, antes de executar a operação PIVOT. Uma forma possível é através da função COUNT (usada como função de janela).

Fica aqui a instrução e o link para o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eac75/5).

```
SELECT  [ID Rep]
       ,[Binder]
       ,[Desk]
       ,[Pen]
       ,[Pen Set]
       ,[Pencil]
       ,[TotalRep]
  FROM 
  (
       SELECT  [Item]
              ,[Customer ID]
              ,[ID Rep]
              ,COUNT([Item]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID Rep]) AS TotalRep
         FROM [dbo].[WRK_Transacoes] 
   ) AS TabUm 
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT([Customer ID])
    FOR [Item] IN (
                    [Binder]
                   ,[Desk]
                   ,[Pen Set]
                   ,[Pen]
                   ,[Pencil])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Eis solução que emprega o pivot clássico, através da cláusula GROUP BY:

```
-- código #1
SELECT [ID Rep], 
       sum(case when Item = 'Binder' then 1 else 0 end) as Binder,
       sum(case when Item = 'Desk' then 1 else 0 end) as Desk,
       sum(case when Item = 'Pen Set' then 1 else 0 end) as [Pen Set],
       sum(case when Item = 'Pen' then 1 else 0 end) as Pen,
       sum(case when Item = 'Pencil' then 1 else 0 end) as Pencil, 
       count(*) as Total
  from dbo.WRK_Transacoes
  where Item in ('Binder', 'Desk', 'Pen Set', 'Pen', 'Pencil')
  group by [ID Rep];
```

Essa forma, pivô clássico, e outras estão descritas no artigo “[Alas & Pivôs](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/05/04/pivot/)”. Explicação passo a passo.